# open chrome from terminal with flags on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, google-chrome

On Mac OS, I can run chrome with certain flags set like this:

```
chrome http://localhost:8080 --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

What is the equivalent command for Windows 10?

```
start chrome http://localhost:8080 --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required
```

results in

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I turns out that the command I had is **corrent IF** you run it from the **default terminal**, or hyper, just not from powershell.